# How to pass parameter to function on pub/sub using nettcpbinding

Tags: c#-4.0, wcf-binding, publish-subscribe, nettcpbinding

i am newbie to nettcpbinding callback function,

i have scenario where i need to get the result based on the parameter pass ex. messageId and get the result data when publisher publised based on messageId to the subscribe client.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `KnownType` attribute.

Your result classes have to inherit from a base class which is decorated with all the possible derived classes:

```
[KnownType( typeof( ResultClassOne ) )]
[KnownType( typeof( ResultClassTwo ) )]
class ResultBase
{
  public int MessageId { get; set; }
}

class ResultClassOne : ResultBase
{
  ... other properties
}

class ResultClassTwo : ResultBase
{
  ... other properties
}
```

This will allow all derived classes to be serialized properly.

Then use the base class in your contract interface:

```
ResultBase Method( int messageId )
```

And in the implementation, pass back instances of the correct derived class:

```
public ResultBase Method( int messageId )
{
  if ( messageId == 1 ) return new ResultClassOne();
  ...
```

Comment: Nichols, one confusion, what if i want to fetch the data from database based on messageId passed.

Comment: That depends on what framework are you using for database access, but at some point you're going to have to write code to call different database queries for different `messageIds`

Comment: Nichol, i think question was not asked properly(i am aware on DB side).but i got the solution.. Thanks,,